# Cannot data bind to <input> in Polymer 2.0

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to get the user input from my `<paper-input-container>` using this code:

```
<paper-input-container id="nameInput">
  <label slot="label">Your name</label>
  <iron-input slot="input">
    <input on-keydown="keypressed" value="{{first}}" id="nameBox">
  </iron-input>
</paper-input-container>
```

In my `properties`, I have:

```
static get properties() {
  return {
     first:{
       type:String,
       value:''
     }
  }
}
```

and my `keypressed` function is:

```
keypressed(e) {
    console.log(this.first);
}
```

I've been able to get it to work with the `<paper-input>` element, but I wasn't able to style it the way I wanted to. If you know how to increase the user input text size on paper-input in Polymer 2.0, that would also help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polymer's [change notification](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#change-events) requires an event naming convention that the native `<input>` does not follow, so the two-way data binding you seek requires [special syntax](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#two-way-native), as shown here:

```
target-prop="{{hostProp::target-change-event}}"
```

In your case, that would be:

```
<input value="{{first::input}}>
```

This tells Polymer to set `first` equal to `value` when the `input` event occurs from the `<input>`. This is equivalent to:

```
const inputEl = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('input');
inputEl.addEventListener('input', () => this.first = value);
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/YQxPEe?editors=1010)

Alternatively, you could bind `first` to `<iron-input>.bindValue`, which reflects the `value` of `<input>`:

```
<iron-input bind-value="{{first}}">
  <input>
</iron-input>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QgMwPw?editors=1011)

> if you know how to increase the user input text size on paper-input in polymer 2.0, that would also help

The font-size of the `<paper-input>`'s inner `<input>` can be styled with the [`--paper-input-container-input`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/elements/paper-input-container#styling) CSS property of `<paper-input-container>`:

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-input {
        --paper-input-container-input: {
          font-size: 40px;
        };
      }
    </style>
    <paper-input label="My label" value="My value"></paper-input>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/dRzPBK?editors=1010)

Comment: @L.Lasiter No problem :)